# "An error occured while applying security settings" during node.js installation

Tags: node.js, windows, installation

I am trying to update my node.js version. I managed to delete it, but I can't install a new version. Any suggestions?

[image: error message]

Comment: pls provide which language and version. It may be related to this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224

Comment: I think so. Windows 10, 19042, rus localization. Node 14.17 or 16.4 both not installing. Thx for your message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a known issue

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224

> Core issue seems to be that Windows localizes names of built-in users
> and groups. On my non-English Windows system, there does not exist a
> group called "Authenticated Users". It exists using a localized name.
> Hence, the solution implemented in that commit will never work on
> non-English Windows systems.

Comment: Yep, thx! Installed 16.4.0 for now. Awaiting a fix in the future.